I need to filter the records from a table in Toad Oracle
I need to filter the records from a table based on the logic outlined below, in Toad Oracle.
Logic is:

If customer.ID and customer.ORDERID combination has customer.CODE with values 'TT' and 'TP', load value 'TP' and ignore 'TT'.

Note: ID and ORDERID columns can have multiple rows.
I am unable to put this logic into a WHERE clause and also not able to understand how I can select and exclude the records based on the given logic. Please assist me on this.
I tried GROUP BY, but it's not working as I am fetching all columns of the table.

please provide sample data and desired output

lets say customer table having 2 rows only:
1st row - ID is 10, CUSTOMERID is 2 and CODE value is TT.                                          2nd row - ID is 20, CUSTOMERID is 3 and CODE value is TP.                                               So I need that my sql should select only 2nd row with value TP.

sorry, but sample data and provided description does not match each other. Based on on your comment SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE CODE='TP'

Also, please update/edit your question with any additional information. If you use comments then it can become difficult to understand what the current state of your question is - and you can’t format text in comments


If customer.ID and customer.ORDERID combination has customer.CODE with values 'TT' and 'TP', load value 'TP' and ignore 'TT'.

From Oracle 12, use DENSE_RANK and a CASE expression in an ORDER BY statement to prioritise TP rows over TT and then use FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES to get the highest priority rows in each group:
SELECT *
FROM   customer
WHERE  code IN ('TT', 'TP')
ORDER BY
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (
         PARTITION BY id, orderid
         ORDER BY CASE code WHEN 'TP' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
       )
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES

In earlier versions you can filter in an inline-view:
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT c.*,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (
           PARTITION BY id, orderid
           ORDER BY CASE code WHEN 'TP' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
         ) AS rnk
  FROM   customer c
  WHERE  code IN ('TT', 'TP')
)
WHERE  rnk = 1

